# How to test order of parameters C#

Tags: c#, cqrs

I am currently working on a CQRS system.

It uses Commands and Events which is standard practice. Commands and Events are just .NET classes but these classes often contain a number of Id's as Properties and these Id's are all Guids.

This leads to a problem when constructing the classes. There is a big if not huge risk that someone on the team will call the constructor with parameters in the wrong order. You can imagine how this simple problem will be devastating i.e. OrderId assigned to CustomerId and vice versa.

So I am looking for ideas how to solve this.

I have some ideas myself.

1. Make a seperate Type for each Id. I.e. replace guid with lots of types. This is the obvious OO solution. But I do not like it for a number of reasons.
2. Consistent naming and Unittesting: If we always name our Id's like Id. We can potentially test that the parameterlist in the caller and callee is the same (or similar). And ignore cases when we just use Guid.NewGuid(). The test is not simple though. For the parameters of the method called, it is quite easy to get the parameter list using Reflection or Mono.Reflection. For the caller it is another matter. Variables in the method might be optimized away for instance. So for testing the caller we will need to do something other than reflection, along the lines of stylecop for instance.

All in all I am not sold on either idea, and would like something simpler or perhaps a ready made solution ?

Comment: Using a discrete type is the "safest" inside the type-system, but this only pushes when the values may be accidentally crossed or mixed up to a different level. Consistent naming is good regardless and correct testing is required (for semantic validation, e.g. ordering of same-typed field) anyway. (Also, using a different type/discreet type is not strictly related to OOP.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem, and would be a better fit for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that this really has anything to do with CQRS.  It has more to do with passing values as parameters to a constructor or method with more than one parameter of the same type.  The answers will certainly be opinionated, and could vary drastically.

Comment: Enforce a policy of using named arguments.

Comment: Interesting. That might actually be the best solution. But only if it is possible on specific assemblies. I will look into if it is possible with Resharper.

Comment: To Matt Johnson. Yeah it is not only CQRS, just more so than "ordinary" systems, because of the extensive use of Guid's as parameters. I have been developing professionally for 20 years. And have never seen this as a huge problem before coding this CQRS system. BTW if this is off-topic then it is ok for me if someone with the correct priviliges moves it. :)

Comment: Or perhaps have empty constructors and use object initializers.

Comment: Good argument for Object initializers, but not a good idea I think. The constructor or a factory method with parameters ensure that all relevant parameters are used. When using object initializers it is up to the callers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate type for each id is good solution but I don't like it also.

Unit testing method calls is very hard problem. Consistent naming is always good.

In my opinion too many parameters in commands/events is first signal that something is wrong. Maybe command is responsible for too many things or some parameters can be deliver via infrastructure (like current user identity).

EDIT:
If you can make sure that there will be no Order and Customer (for example) with the same Id (I think that with GUIDs it is safe assumption) you can verify that both exists and if someone somewhere mix these two values there will always be an error in runtime, so mistake will be spotted easily.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you to an extent. But the problem is there even with only two parameters.

Comment: That's true but it is impossible to replace thinking with machine (I hope so ;)). I've added another idea to solve this problem

Comment: Your edit is interesting but I would also need an AOP framework for that I think. Because I cannot just test that both values exists - because they do - I have to test that they match the correct property. Or perhaps I do not follow you correctly ? Anyway with AOP I could inject code that validated the properties using either yours or Peter Smiths idea. So perhaps AOP is actually the answer...

Comment: I mean: check that customer with given id really exists

Comment: I would need to check that in a validation method which would need to be called by the constructor. Hence the need for an AOP framework to inject that code automatically. To do it manually would be tedious.

Comment: I have a solution now, that mostly uses the idea from your "Edit". In the base class of commands and events I store the command/event in isolated storage in a List. Later I run a test that stores the Guid and name of the Guid property. If there is ever a mismatch i.e. same guid was earlier stored as customerid, but now as orderid. Then I know something is wrong. All this I do only in DEBUG mode. Big thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One thought would be to prefix the GUID (as they are strings) with a type identifier. So, pseudo-GUID
for customer ID `xxyy`  becomes `cust_xxyy` however, as C# strongly-types I would suggest class and properties as the correct way of doing this.

Comment: The prefix thing is an interesting idea, but I don't see how it is viable. Then I would need to validate the guid/string in all method calls ? Well if I used som AOP framework then perhaps. Your last statement is the same as my 1. idea.

Comment: I was aware of that - just supporting the idea. It feels like the key requirement is to uniquely identify the parameter. Simple is best and sometimes starting by seeming to go backwards just has to happen.

Comment: You are right. But I would clutter the solution with types because all entities have an Id. I would also loose some automatic stuff we have with the Id for the databases. But yes, it is definitely the correct solution from a purist point of view but as stated I am looking for an alternative.